# Get file globs from a file and find these files

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, file-globs

I have a file called "file.txt" and it contains globs. Contents:

```
*.tex
*.pdf
*C*.png
```

I need to get these extensions from the file and then find the files containging these globs in the current directory (preferably using find, anything else is fine too).

I used

```
grep "" file.txt | xargs find . -name
```

but I get this error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: `*.pdf'
```

Using Ubuntu

Comment: Use `xargs -n 1` to prevent it from running `find . -name '*.pdf' '*.txt' '*.whatever'`, putting as many expressions as will fit after `-name` instead of just one.

Comment: That said, what's the point of `grep` here at all?

Comment: How else would I read the contents of the file and redirect them into xargs

Comment: `<file.txt xargs -n 1 find ...` -- no reason for `cat` or `grep` or whatnot. BTW, you can also put the `<file.txt` on the end of the command if you prefer.

Comment: Oh okay. Won't i also have to change the delimiter to '"\n"?

Comment: It's a good idea, but you have that problem with or without `grep`. The output of `grep` contains newlines just as much as the file itself does.

Comment: But yes, in general, `xargs -d $'\n'` has fewer problems than xargs has without `-d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original code needs the `-n 1` argument to be passed to xargs, to pass only one glob to each copy of `find`, as each glob expression needs to be preceded with a `-name` (and attached to any other `-name` expressions with `-o`, the "or" operator).

More efficient is to run `find` just once, after constructing an expression that puts all your `-name` operators on a single command line, separated with `-o`s.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- MUST be run with bash, not /bin/sh

find_expr=( -false )
while IFS= read -r line; do
  find_expr+=( -o -name "$line" )
done <file.txt

find . '(' "${find_expr[@]}" ')' -print
```

Comment: The question restricts me to use a one liner so -n 1 worked. Thankyou :)